# Используя Rider под Linux, почему backspace не удаляет символы при чтени с Console?

Tags: c#, linux, rider

при чтении из Console
при попытки удалить через backspace символ,
блокируется почти весь клавиатурный ввод.

Ситуация такая: я пытаюсь почитать строчку с клавиаутуры в Rider с помощью вот такой не хитрой конструкции `string str = Console.ReadLine();` и вот к примеру я ввел не тот символ и хочу удалить его, как обычно с помощью backspace, но символ не удаляется, как я ожидал, более того все чтение строк с клавы блокируется. Надеюсь максимально понятно объснил суть проблемы.

Comment: Покажите код чтения из консоли

Comment: а в нормальной консоли работает как нужно?

Comment: string readCons = Console.ReadLine();

Comment: да, используя терминал все работает корректно
и в intellijidea при чтении из System.in тоже все норм работает!

Comment: напишу проще)
backspace работает везде корректно, кроме этого момента!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ситуация такая:
я пытаюсь почитать строчку с клавиаутуры в Rider
с помощью вот такой не хитрой конструкции string str = Console.ReadLine();
и вот к примеру я ввел не тот символ и хочу удалить его,
как обычно с помощью backspace, но символ не удаляется, как я ожидал,
более того все чтение строк с клавы блокируется.
Надеюсь максимально понятно объснил суть проблемы.

Comment: Хм, странно. А дополнительных потоков у вас в коде не запускается?

Comment: ну учитывая, что у меня, только лишь одна строчка на чтение в нее:
string readCons = Console.ReadLine();
только, если скрытый от меня поток, где-то инкапсулированный и как-то связанный с классом Console )))
по-фантазировали и хватит :)

Comment: если из под linux пишешь, то попробуй на вкус эту странность ))
это 5-10 мин времени.

Comment: _у меня, только лишь одна строчка_ - это должно быть указано прямо в вопросе! Никому не известно, что там у вас в коде. Может, у вас огромный проект в миллионы строк кода с тысячами пакетов.

Comment: [Console.ReadLine backspace issue on Linux](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29332) - да, на линухе есть проблемы. Не совсем то, но близко.

Comment: Работа с консолью производится очень по-разному на Винде и Линухе. [Тут](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/#system-console), например, описано, с какими трудностями столкнулись разрабы дотнета.